# Tcl binary loop. Binary increment

Tags: tcl, verilog, modelsim

I am trying to write a tcl script for my decoder module (verilog in modelsim)
I need to loop the 'din' input value from from 000 to 111
Thats what i've come up with by now.

```
vsim work.decode_shift
add wave -noupdate -format Logic -radix binary  /decode_shift/din
add wave -noupdate -format Logic -radix binary  /decode_shift/dout
for { set i 0 } { $i==0111 } { incr i } {
    force din $i
    run 100
}
run @500ns
```

It doesn't work because of some type issue that i din't know how to bypass. What am i doing wrong and what is the proper way to increment binary digits in tcl?

Comment: isn't that just a loop from 0 to 7? If you need to turn it into a binary string you can use format.

Comment: yes, in decimal. But how do i assign a decimal to binary din?

Comment: i get "Error: (vsim-4011) Invalid force value: 2" as soon as i reaches '2'.

Answer (score 2):

With Tcl, you don't increment binary digits. You format the number as binary. Prior to 8.6, you use a combination of `binary format` and `binary scan` to do the conversion, as here:

```
vsim work.decode_shift
add wave -noupdate -format Logic -radix binary  /decode_shift/din
add wave -noupdate -format Logic -radix binary  /decode_shift/dout
for { set i 0 } { $i<=7 } { incr i } {      # Need non-binary literal
    # Convert to 8 binary digits, store result in “i_bin” variable
    binary scan [binary format c $i] B8 i_bin

    force din $i_bin; # Assume takes 8 bits; [string range] to trim otherwise
    run 100
}
run @500ns
```

If you've got 8.6, you can do this instead:

```
vsim work.decode_shift
add wave -noupdate -format Logic -radix binary  /decode_shift/din
add wave -noupdate -format Logic -radix binary  /decode_shift/dout
for { set i 0 } { $i<=0b111 } { incr i } {   # Binary literal...
    force din [format %04b $i]; # width 4 field, zero padded on left
    run 100
}
run @500ns
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this will help you http://codepad.org/YX4nfMIS (reproduced below) It makes an ascending list of strings representing numbers in binary. But that may not be how Verilog wants your data.

```
set l { "000" "001" "010" "011" "100" "101" "110" "111"}
for { set i 0} { $i<8 } { incr i } {
 puts [lindex $l $i]
}
```

Or as Donal points out

```
set l { "000" "001" "010" "011" "100" "101" "110" "111"}
foreach i $l {
  puts $i
}
```

Comment: You'd be better off using `foreach` in that case; I like `foreach` a lot…

Comment: i also like the simplicity of this one, b/c if you want to change to gray code, it's really easy.